# Your Daily Schedule

Tags: schedule

I try to devote certain time everyday to learn new skills while also improve the older skills that I've gained. But, I'm not hitting the sweet spot where I learn what I want and get things done.

So, I was just curious to know how you guys spend time everyday and "hit the spot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Google reader and just add more and more tech blogs as I find them.  Then, I read them in the morning with coffee.  This site provides quite a bit of education as well.

Comment: www.codinghorror.com/blog, www.joelonsoftware.com, www.randsinrepose.com, http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/Default.aspx

Plenty in these three that will guide you to others along the way

Answer (score 1):

I read technical websites everyday. I like to use Google reader as well since it tracks what I've read and allows me to easily continue where I left off from any computer I happen to have access to.

I started out with the basics : [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/), [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/)
, and [Dr. Dobb's Journal](http://www.ddj.com). These sites will frequently lead to other great sources of information.

When following sites like this using an RSS feed, you don't have to read every article that comes through. Just scan them over and read the ones that catch your interest. Without realizing it, you will store away alot of information that will pop back into your head when you encounter a situation that triggers it.

You won't necessarily be a master of everything you read but you will be at least aware of current developments and technologies.

The second part is to practice. I usually have some simple and enjoyable programming project on the go at home all the time. I may not actually complete anything useful but I use it as a basis to try out new things. Alot of times I will encounter a problem at work and find that I've already explored some of the solutions at home or at least thought about them and will be able to make a much more informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

Tech blogs are a great way to find out basic information on new material and sometimes they will even have a more in-depth feature that can leave you with some take-away knowledge than just another tech headline.

What works best for me is to identify topics that I have read in tech blogs that interest me and then find sources that provide me with more advanced information on the subject. Then as the week goes by spend however much time needed to digest the information learning the material.

Just browsing tech headlines all day, in my opinion, won't leave you with any distilled information beyond basic advances in technology. Actually diving in and spending X amount of time each day learning material that is interesting to you will be infinitely better.

Answer (score 0):

I find the key to getting things done is to manage distrations.  I process email in batches only once or twice per day, and try to avoid phone calls, meetings and IM where I can.  This leaves me bigger chinks of time available for development.

I learn new skills in a couple of different ways...  Firstly reading a load of developmetn related tech blogs via an RSS reader.  This allows me to absorb a continuous flow of new ideas without necessarily "learning" a lot, but saves me a lot of time on research later.  Then when I run into something new, chances are something I've already read will be of assistance and I can dig in an "learn" something in more detail.

e.g. Through regular RSS reading I became aware that a significant number of javascript frameworks had been developed and it seemed to make more sense to use a js framework than coding DOM manipulation by hand.  Later when I started a new project that was going to be heavy on Ajax, I was able to name a couple of frameworks off the top of my head,quickly pick one and really dig in and get to know it.